# How to find exact match values in 3 columns and change the row values in dataframe

Tags: python

I have two tables, a source, and dict, where the main point is to get find an exact match from dict table in tablecampaignsource and substitute the old values with new values disregarding the case. The first table looks like this:

tableCampaignSource

| date | medium | network | campaign | users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/01/2022 | OOh | offline | campaignB | 5 |
| 1/01/2022 | offline | flyer | campaignC | 6 |
| 2/01/2022 | OOH | offline | campaignB | 6 |
| 02/01/2022 | offline | flyer | campaignA | 6 |
| 02/01/2022 | paidAds | facebook | campaignC | 7 |
| 02/01/2022 | cpc | facebook | campaignD | 7 |

dictionary Table

| medium | network | campaign | newMedium | newNetwork | newCampaign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OOh | offline | campaignB | offline | OOH | campaign B |
| cpc | facebook | campaignD | paidAds | facebook | campaignD |

Where I want to use the dictionary table field medium, network, campaign to substitute into table campaign source

where it will become

| date | medium | network | campaign | users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/01/2022 | OOh | offline | campaignB | 5 |
| 1/01/2022 | offline | flyer | campaignC | 6 |
| 2/01/2022 | offline | flyer | campaignB | 6 |
| 02/01/2022 | offline | flyer | campaignA | 6 |
| 02/01/2022 | paidAds | facebook | campaignC | 7 |
| 02/01/2022 | paidAds | facebook | campaignD | 7 |

Do I try to use a list approach making a delimited list and exact match or is there a faster way?

```
tableCampaignSource['concate']= tableCampaignSource['medium']0+","+tableCampaignSource['network']+","+tableCampaignSource['campaign']
listConcate =  list (tableCampaignSource['concate']).values
```

how do you map the values? like index match in excel?In excel it's like ifna(index(a,match(value,range,0))  where I used the concated list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge two dataframes on three columns

```py
df = pd.merge(tableCampaignSource, dictionary, how='left', left_on=['medium', 'network', 'campaign'], right_on = ['medium', 'network', 'campaign'])
```

```
         date   medium   network   campaign  users newMedium newNetwork newCampaign
0   1/01/2022      OOh   offline  campaignB      5   offline        OOH   campaignB
1   1/01/2022  offline     flyer  campaignC      6       NaN        NaN         NaN
2   2/01/2022      OOH   offline  campaignB      6       NaN        NaN         NaN
3  02/01/2022  offline     flyer  campaignA      6       NaN        NaN         NaN
4  02/01/2022  paidAds  facebook  campaignC      7       NaN        NaN         NaN
5  02/01/2022      cpc  facebook  campaignD      7   paidAds   facebook   campaignD
```

Then update the `tableCampaignSource` original columns by matched new columns with [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```py
import numpy as np

tableCampaignSource[['medium', 'network', 'campaign']] = np.where(pd.notnull(df[['newMedium', 'newNetwork', 'newCampaign']]), df[['newMedium', 'newNetwork', 'newCampaign']], df[['medium', 'network', 'campaign']])
```

```
         date   medium   network   campaign  users
0   1/01/2022  offline       OOH  campaignB      5
1   1/01/2022  offline     flyer  campaignC      6
2   2/01/2022      OOH   offline  campaignB      6
3  02/01/2022  offline     flyer  campaignA      6
4  02/01/2022  paidAds  facebook  campaignC      7
5  02/01/2022  paidAds  facebook  campaignD      7
```